# AWS DMS - check volume of transfered data within time range

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-dms

Is there a quick way to check how many data (volume wise, GBs, TBs etc) did my specific DMS task transfered for example within last month?

I can't find any note in the documentation on that, I could probably try with `boto3` but want to double check first. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with `Boto3`, you can check the API - `DescribeReplicationTasks` but likely, there is no information about your data transfer.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeReplicationTasks.html

If you have only 1 data replication task that is associated with only 1 replication instance, you can check that replication instance's network metric via **CloudWatch** metric. From **CloudWatch** metrics, `AWS DMS` namespace, there will be several network metrics such as `NetworkTransitThroughput` or `NetworkReceiveThroughput`. You can choose one and try as below:

- Statistic: Sum
- Period: 30 days (or up to you)

And you have a `30DAYS_THROUGHPUT`.